# calculating Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I know what the Laplace Transform of a function

$\exp(-x(t))$

is, where $x(t)$ is positive for all $t$. Is there any way to calculate what the Laplace Transform of

$\frac{1}{1-\exp(-x(t))}$

is?

I have tried with the geometrical series, but then I still do not know how to calculate the Laplace Transform of

$\exp(-kx(t))$,

which occurs in the formula (for $k=2,3,...$). One can assume that the function $x(t)$ is "enough nice" if this is needed (i.e. differentiable, continuous or what is necessary).

Comment: Are you saying that x is some **unknown** function of t?

Comment: Yes, x(t) is unknown, but I know that the Laplace Transform of \exp(-x(t)) is, e.g., m(u). I want to write the Laplace Transform of \frac{1}{1- \exp(-x(t))} in terms of m(u).